# Deaddiction and neural plasticity in case of the elderly

Tags: neurology, addiction, nicotine

It is [known](https://www.nature.com/articles/npp2017280) that prolonged nicotine use alters the brain's connectivity. *Nicotine exerts its neurophysiologic action principally through the brain’s reward center*.[2](https://www.medscape.com/answers/287555-158502/what-is-the-pathophysiology-of-nicotine-addiction) *Neuroadaptation develops with repeated exposure to nicotine, resulting in tolerance to many of the effects of nicotine.*[3](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/18342164/)

*Recovery involves a major change in thoughts and feelings, and such changes require ongoing neural development or neuroplasticity.* [4](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/addicted-brains/201512/recovery-addiction-relies-neuroplasticity) So quitting a long term addiction will involve rewiring in the brain. Which in turn is dependent on neural plasticity.

*Thus, age-related dysregulation of calcium signaling may underlie deficits in neural plasticity, and may ultimately be responsible for cognitive decline that occurs in the healthy, non-demented aging population.* [5](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780124115965000149)

To summarize: quitting a long term addiction requires brain plasticity, which in turn is in deficit in older populations.

So are the elderly neurologically just as capable of overcoming addictions as the young?

Comment: Nice job revamping this question. I added one final tweak by removing your second question that was entirely an opinion poll.

Comment: I also wonder (as the question seems to centre on calcium signalling and neuroplasticity) whether this question may be better with the neuroscientists at Psychology&Neuroscience.SE

Comment: @ChrisRogers Yes, I think it would be a better fit there.

Comment: @ChrisRogers Yes, you are right, that would be a much better fit. I even have an account and had asked a question on the psychology and neuro SE. Somehow it didn't cross my mind while asking this question.

Comment: @CareyGregory Yes, even I like the revamped version better; thanks for pushing me in that direction.